# Re-use (through query statements) a data array from an import formula in Google Sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to retrieve a list of values of from distinct but identical schema tables.
However, I'm trying to reduce the number of `ImportHTML` call-outs that sheets has to make for best performance. Some issues I'm running into:

Using "Scrape data from Wikipedia to a Google sheet" as an example:

In a new sheet where A1 =
`=ImportHtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)", "table", 4)`

1. Is it possible to use the data without expanding the result?

   For instance when I have data in nearby columns:

   [image: Example constrained ImportHTML]

1.b) Is it possible to query that `A1` result even when it is in a `#REF!` error?

2. What is the best practice to perform a single import table and (without expansion) query that array data multiple times?

   [image: Example query pointing at source only]

I'm aware that if I allowed for expansion, I would be able to query like:

`=query(A1:F100,"select F where A = 'India'")`

Comment: What about doing your import into a separate tab (in your sheet) and then all of the queries can be run against that imported data?  I can't think of any way to have multiple queries to your data array, unless you store it somewhere in your sheet - unless you did it with a script, where you could have the imported data values "pushed" to multiple parts of your sheet.  But this wouldn't be as dynamic as having the data available for repeated queries, with dynamic criteria, if necessary.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@nabais's answer had gotten the juices flowing and I was actually able to retrieve the table format as a single string and then use find functions to retrieve the data I needed.

Example:

```
=CONCATENATE(IMPORTHTML(CONCATENATE("https://finviz.com/quote.ashx?t=",Watchlist!$A4),"table",9))
```

Which produces a string like:

```
Index*DJIA S&P500*P/E*35.92*EPS (ttm)*3.27*Insider Own*0.07%*Shs Outstand*17.06B*Perf Week*-1.61%*Market Cap*1994.16B*Forward P/E*27.26*EPS next Y*4.31*Insider Trans*-6.88%*Shs Float*16.99B*Perf Month*1.37%*Income*57.41B*PEG*2.84*EPS next Q*1.39*Inst Own*61.70%*Short Float*0.47%*Perf Quarter*-6.77%*Sales*274.52B*P/S*7.26*EPS this Y*10.20%*Inst Trans*-*Short Ratio*0.52*Perf Half Y*48.19%*Book/sh*3.83*P/B*30.64*EPS next Y*8.99%*ROA*17.60%*Target Price*123.11*Perf Year*79.14%*Cash/sh*5.35*P/C*21.93*EPS next 5Y*12.64%*ROE*75.20%*52W Range*53.15 - 137.98*Perf YTD*59.84%*Dividend*0.82*P/FCF*33.64*EPS past 5Y*7.30%*ROI*31.70%*52W High*-14.96%*Beta*1.33*Dividend %*0.70%*Quick Ratio*1.30*Sales past 5Y*3.30%*Gross Margin*38.20%*52W Low*120.76%*ATR*3.15*Employees*147000*Current Ratio*1.40*Sales Q/Q*1.00%*Oper. Margin*24.10%*RSI (14)*52.96*Volatility*1.72% 2.66%*Optionable*Yes*Debt/Eq*1.73*EPS Q/Q*-3.00%*Profit Margin*20.90%*Rel Volume*0.47*Prev Close*118.64*Shortable*Yes*LT Debt/Eq*1.52*Earnings*Oct 29 AMC*Payout*24.10%*Avg Volume*154.64M*Price*117.34*Recom*2.10*SMA20*1.13%*SMA50*1.75%*SMA200*25.71%*Volume*72,188,812*Change*-1.10%*
```

And can then be parsed for a particular data value using something like:

```
=IFERROR(VALUE(substitute(LEFT(MID(MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21),FIND("*",MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21))+1,LEN(MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21))),FIND("*",MID(MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21),FIND("*",MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21))+1,LEN(MID(<stringcell>,FIND("Rel Volume",<stringcell>),21))))-1),"%",""))/100,"Not Found")
```

Answer (score 2):

I tried to do some tests to understand how google sheets fetched the information.

What I have done was:

- created a `request bin` to see when the requests were being made,
- imported the HTML with as many different ways I could:

  - `importhtml(urlInCell)`
  - `importhtml(urlInFormula)`
  - `query({importhtml(urlInCell), importhtml(urlInFormula)})`

The result was that google sheets only made the request once and cached the imported value for all those requests, and I tried closing and reopening the sheet, refreshing and even hard-refreshing, and the request was still only made once. As seen below:

[image]

Then, I tried to query the results by calling the way you do above, and it didn't work as well.

The only solution for what you wanted exactly to make would be to query the data directly from the `importhtml` with:

`=query(ImportHtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)", "table", 4),"select Col6 where Col1='India'")`

[image]

### suggestion

My suggestion here would be to fetch the data into a sheet on its own and then query the entire sheet in another place:

- Sheet Info - `=ImportHtml("https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_countries_by_population_(United_Nations)", "table", 4)`
- Target Sheet - `=query(Info!A:Z, "select F where A = 'India'")`

### tests

Here is the image with the tests I did and their results
[image]

Hope it helps, if you need further information let me know in the comments